# A two-factor authentication app that runs on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, two-factor-authentication

Most two factor authentication apps are available for Android or iOS. I do not use a smartphone. Is there a two factor authentication app that runs on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I've found is the Authy Chrome plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authy/gaedmjdfmmahhbjefcbgaolhhanlaolb?hl=en

I generally use Firefox, but you can install the app and let it create a desktop icon / app menu entry. Then you can launch it like a normal app.